# packer Objects in user variables

Tags: json, packer

How to load a user variable object from a var file. The question was asked here https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/2441

> is it possible to handle objects in user variables? For example using
>   the chef-solo provisioner I would like to pass the json attributes as
>   a user variable. It seems like with the current implementation this is
>   not possible.
>
> Error reading variables in 'test.json': json: cannot unmarshal object
>   into Go value of type string
>
> I have a file called test.json that looks contains the following:
>
> { "metadata":{"somekey":"somevalue"} }
>
> I receive the error above when passing the file in with the var-file
>   option.
>
> is there a specific reason this is not implemented? It would not be
>   necessary to parse the deeply nested object it would just need to set
>   the user variable metadata to an object so it could be used by object
>   types in the packer.json

There is a workaround but I need an example of it.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like with the current implementation this is not possible.

That is correct, currently passing objects in user variables is not possible.

You can simply pre-process in the value you need, e.g. with `jq`:

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "digitalocean",
    "ssh_pty": "true",
    "image": "{{user `di_image`}}",
    "region": "{{user `di_region`}}",
    "size": "{{user `di_size`}}"
    }]
 }
```

`cat cloud.json | jq 'setpath(["builders",0,"flavor"]; {"hi": "hoo"})'`

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "digitalocean",
    "ssh_pty": "true",
    "image": "{{user `di_image`}}",
    "region": "{{user `di_region`}}",
    "size": "{{user `di_size`}}",
    "flavor": {
      "hi": "hoo"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the example. The idea is to pass an object as a variable. I do not see how is that possible using your example?